Zeta Lerch function. Proof of functional equation.
so I'm trying to prove the functional equation of Lerch Zeta, through the Hankel contour and Residue theorem, did the following.
In the article "Note sur la function" by Mr. Mathias Lerch, a complex function is defined:
$$ R(w,x,s)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2\pi ikx}}{(w+k)^s} $$
Having the integral over Hermann Hankel's contour:
$$ K(w,x,s)=\int_H\frac{z^{s-1}e^{-wx}}{1-e^{2\pi ix-z}}dz $$
The relationship between R and K is as follows:
$$ R(w,x,s)=\frac{e^{-s\pi i}}{2\pi i}\Gamma(1-s)K(w,x,s) $$
But using the residue theorem on K we get:
$$ \frac{ie^{2\pi iwx}}{(2\pi)^{s}}K(w,x,s)= $$
$$ =e^{-\frac{\pi i}{2}(1-s)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2\pi ikw}}{(x+k)^{1-s}} + e^{2\pi iw+\frac{\pi i}{2}(1-s)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2\pi ikw}}{(1-x+k)^{1-s}} $$
And then there's a moment in the article that I don't understand. There is something written in French. You can download the original here:
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-11/issue-none/Note-sur-la-fonction-mathfrakKw-x-s--sumlimits_k-/10.1007/BF02612318.full
I don't understand this:
$$ (x+k)^{1-s}=[(x+k)^{1-s}] $$ and $$ (1-x+k)^{1-s}=e^{2\pi i(1-s)}[(1-x+k)^{1-s}] $$
I suspect that it is about the complex argument, Riemann surfaces and some kind of discontinuity, "branch cut". And while I know how it works with contour integration, I don't understand it here.
Why do we multiply by the exponent for the series with 1-x+k but not for the series with x+k? (please, step by step) It is important, because it changes final result which is functional equation.

Without going through the full paper, the first full paragraph on p. 23 reads, "We've only defined the function ${\mathfrak R}$ for real and positive values of $w$. Denote by $[u^{\sigma}]$ the quantity $e^{\sigma \log u}$, the imaginary part of $\log u$ being between the bounds $(-\pi, \dots, \pi)$, so that the function $[u^{\sigma}]$ is continuous and uniform on the space of points $u$ outside the cut $(-\infty, \dots 0)$, along which it's discontinuous." (Or something like that; my technical vocabulary here is a bit weak.) Short answer: There's a branch cut to define $u^{\sigma}$.

Even shorter answer: Because of the branch cut, we don't have $[u^{\sigma} u^{\sigma'}] = [u^{\sigma + \sigma'}]$. That discrepancy is the cause of the difference in those two equations.

Well it is still not clear for me. Why $$ arg(x+k)=0 $$ and $$ arg(1-x+k)=2\pi $$ ?

Not sure what the conventions on $x$ are without going through the whole paper, but $x + k$ and $1 - x + k$ have opposite signs on their imaginary parts ($k$ is an integer here), and the discussion at the bottom of p. 20 should give you the necessary argument.

I understand your way of thinking, but I still expect a less heuristic and more rigorous answer. Maybe someone else will know.
